# How to mix Union and Intersection types Flow annotations?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I keep running into this scenario where I have trouble typing some resources from an API. Here is a small repro of the typical situation.

I have a `DescribableResource` that can be either of type `ResourceA` or `ResourceB`. Each of these 2 types have a common base and some specific props, as follow:

```js
type Base = {
  version: string,
  name: string,
  year: number
};

type ResourceA = Base & {
  mySpecificA: string
};

type ResourceB = Base & {
  mySpecificB: string
};

type DescribableResource = ResourceA | ResourceB;
```

Now, I have a component in charge of receiving a `DescribableResource` and displaying its content on screen.

```
type Props = {
  +resource: DescribableResource
};

function ResourceDescriptor({ resource }: Props) {
  const { version, name, year, mySpecificA, mySpecificB } = resource;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{version}</div>
      <div>{name}</div>
      <div>{year}</div>
      {mySpecificA && <div>{mySpecificA}</div>}
      {mySpecificB && <div>{mySpecificB}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code works fine, but I get the following Flow errors:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/ResourceDescriptor.js:25:32

All branches are incompatible:
 • Either property mySpecificA is missing in Base [1].
 • Or property mySpecificA is missing in object type [2].

 [1][2] 14│ type ResourceB = Base & {
        15│   mySpecificB: string
        16│ };
          :
        22│ };
        23│
        24│ function ResourceDescriptor({ resource }: Props) {
        25│   const { version, name, year, mySpecificA, mySpecificB } = resource;
        26│
        27│   return (
        28│     <div>


Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ src/ResourceDescriptor.js:25:45

All branches are incompatible:
 • Either property mySpecificB is missing in Base [1].
 • Or property mySpecificB is missing in object type [2].

 [1][2] 10│ type ResourceA = Base & {
        11│   mySpecificA: string
        12│ };
          :
        22│ };
        23│
        24│ function ResourceDescriptor({ resource }: Props) {
        25│   const { version, name, year, mySpecificA, mySpecificB } = resource;
        26│
        27│   return (
        28│     <div>
```

[Demo of these errors on Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoSmATzCTgCEUBnegXjgG9y44A3JFGbAIAOwBccZjCjBRAcwA0POKJQgkk6bIXLe1VFEmiAriABGg8gF8K5GnURJmEE1DRIAgnA5NWcADIuFRBqAGU6NGBMYDRPLRk5eRs7B3pkFzcPBh9GFnog7l5QiKQomLQGBJ1k2ypaegARZzRZcxRzABskDNd3didM-u8AH0G+7Lt7BrgABRwwZlyiuABqIiGPSWbmVuB2rp7nCaQUykwTUQwRUXGspB29sBhoAApOOA2TuGtJeYhFgBKYK8NBiaRcfiCYRiRSqdRIOEGFBQOElSLRWKeNHhDEVHLWXJfe52XhEGBuW6vFS8AA8ABNgHwAHw03hwBlM5mcARCG7WWkAekZLLZdJF3LUGgFwq5Yo5Es4yKgMol8s46LKmLigSCnJZGtxWoqnlVXOs6s15ViOQCesVVu1DDNLIt7I5stFvEBFGsQA)

I can't tell whether I'm doing something wrong in my type definitions or if it's a Flow bug. Help would be very welcome.

Comment: An example call of `ResourceDescriptor` you can use for testing the types: `ResourceDescriptor({resource: { version: '1.3.0', name: 'cat', year: 1995, mySpecificB: 'Japanese Bobtail' }})`. Also, note that the errors may be easier to read if you extract out `ResourceDescriptor`’s destructured object property assignments such as `const mySpecificA = resource.mySpecificA;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work like that, because it's not safe. `Base` type can have a `mySpecificA` property, as it's not limited to these three properties (note the difference between `{...}` and `{|...|}`). To let Flow actually check, if the `resource` prop has a given key, you have to distinguish these two types somehow. For example, restrict possible properties using spread instead of intersection:

```js
// Most of the non-changed parts are skipped.

type Base = {
  version: string,
  name: string,
  year: number
};

type ResourceA = {
  ...Base,
  mySpecificA: string
};

type ResourceB = {
  ...Base,
  mySpecificB: string
};

function ResourceDescriptor({ resource }: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Just works. */}
      {typeof resource.mySpecificB === 'string' && <div>{resource.mySpecificA}</div>}

      {/* Works only if exact objects are being used in all three types. */}
      {resource.mySpecificA && <div>{resource.mySpecificA}</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, if an object of type `DescribableResource` has a `mySpecificA` property, it's clear, that this is of type `ResourceA`.

There's a set of problems when mixing intersections with unions, like [facebook/flow#4029](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4029) or [facebook/flow#4247](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4247), which may be related.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea you could spread Flow types this way. I had tried many many many options but never thought of that one. I had totally overlooked this section in the docs: https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types